# Database Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: diagrams, database

Is there a package that will allow me to create a database entity relationship diagram such as the one below?

[image]

Comment: The question of "how to draw Database Entity-Relationship diagram" received an excellent answer [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82600/34551). It does not cover the particular case @sduplooy was looking at, but is much much extensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it with `xelatex`or `latex=>dvips=>ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,pst-node,pst-dbicons}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}
\def\Tab#1{\tabular{C{3cm}}\rule[-5mm]{0pt}{1cm}#1\\\hline
                           ~\\\hline~\endtabular}
\seticonparams{entity}{shadow,fillcolor=black!20,fillstyle=solid,framesep=0pt}
\begin{document}

\entity{students}[\Tab{Students}]\hspace{2.5cm}
\entity{courses}[\Tab{Courses}]
\ncline[arrowscale=2]{->}{students}{courses}
\naput[npos=0.1]{1}\naput{take}\naput[npos=0.85]{1..*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use TikZ. Have a look at the [TikZ diagram examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/).

Another possibility is [PSTricks](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/).