# Drawing relationships between elements of a database

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, database

I am looking into a feasible way of drawing relationships between Elements from a database. An example: Element x is related to Element Y via the Role "sister".

Relationships exist in the form 1:1, 1:n or m:n, so one element may link to >1 other elements, there are also >1 element types and >1 role types.

Right now it is done manually in Powerpoint, which is really prone to errors. Is there a suitable way to draw these diagrams via TikZ/PGF or any other software? I'd love to write some SQL script to get me the list of elements with their relationship and have e.g. Python prepare the TeX Code. The major challenge is for me, that I have no clue how many elements come from the database and I would like to have LaTeX do the positioning.

[image]

Comment: I think [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) can help. `:)` And we can also use the [`dot2texi`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/dot2texi) package to embed graphs written in `.dot` in our `.tex` documents. `:)`

Comment: Another possibility is [tikz-er2](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/tikz-er2). You find also an example [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/entity-relationship-diagram/).

Comment: Would either of you post GraphiViz or tikz-er2 as answer, then i'll accept. Both are quite good and will help me a lot.

Comment: Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58389/db-diagrams-entity-relationship-tikz-chamfered-rectangle-with-split-zones. Is it what you searh to ?

Comment: It is weird that the keywords "database Entity-relationship diagram" or "ER diagram" does not appear on this page, so, here they are `;-)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As said in the comments, two approaches could be used. I first introduce them and later on I'll try to explain a bit which are the pros and cons of both.

I start with the [`tikz-er2`](https://bitbucket.org/pavel_calado/tikz-er2/raw/7b6d8e2477e7e5c6e9842e569a39d04323c64f63/tikz-er2.sty) package: it's not available on CTAN, thus one should install it by hand.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\tikzset{every entity/.style={draw=orange, fill=orange!20}}
\tikzset{every attribute/.style={draw=MediumPurple1, fill=MediumPurple1!20}}
\tikzset{every relationship/.style={draw=Chartreuse2, fill=Chartreuse2!20}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=7em]
\node[entity] (person) {Person};
\node[attribute] (pid) [left of=person] {\key{ID}} edge (person);
\node[attribute] (name) [above left of=person] {Name} edge (person);
\node[multi attribute] (phone) [above of=person] {Phone} edge (person);
\node[attribute] (address) [above right of=person] {Address} edge (person);
\node[attribute] (street) [above right of=address] {Street} edge (address);
\node[attribute] (city) [right of=address] {City} edge (address);
\node[derived attribute] (age) [right of=person] {Age} edge (person);

\node[relationship] (uses) [below of=person] {Uses} edge (person);
\node[entity] (tool) [below of=uses] {Tool} edge[total] (uses);
\node[attribute] (tid) [left of=tool] {\key{ID}} edge (tool);
\node[attribute] (tname) [right of =tool] {Name} edge (tool);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Here is the [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/) method. The `.dot` language could be used in LaTeX documents inside the environment `dot2tex`, but this requires the [`dot2texi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dot2texi) package and the document should be compiled with `-shell-escape`.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
\tikzset{entity/.style={draw=orange, fill=orange!20}}
\tikzset{attribute/.style={ellipse,draw=MediumPurple1, fill=MediumPurple1!20}}
\tikzset{multi attribute/.style={ellipse,draw=MediumPurple1, fill=MediumPurple1!20,double}}
\tikzset{derived attribute/.style={ellipse,draw=MediumPurple1, fill=MediumPurple1!20,dashed}}
\tikzset{relationship/.style={diamond,draw=Chartreuse2, fill=Chartreuse2!20}}
\tikzset{simple relation/.style={-}}
\tikzset{total relation/.style={-,double}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every state/.style={draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20},]
\begin{dot2tex}[styleonly,codeonly,neato,options=-s -tmath]
digraph G {
d2ttikzedgelabels = true;
edge [lblstyle="auto",topath="-",style="simple relation"];
// nodes
Person [style="entity"];
pid [style="attribute",label="\underline{ID}"];
Attribute [style="attribute"];
Name [style="attribute"];
Phone [style="multi attribute"];
Address [style="attribute"];
Street [style="attribute"];
City [style="attribute"];
Age [style="derived attribute"];
Uses [style="relationship"];
Tool [style="entity"];
tid [style="attribute",label="\underline{ID}"];
tname [style="attribute",label="Name"];
// edges
Person -> pid;
Person -> Attribute;
Person -> Name;
Person -> Phone;
Person -> Address -> Street;
Person -> City;
Person -> Age;
Person -> Uses;
Tool -> tid;
Tool -> tname;
Tool -> Uses[style="total relation"];
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}    

\end{document}
```

as `test_dot.tex`. Now, compiling it with `pdflatex -shell-escape test_dot.tex`, you will end up with:

[image]

Notice, besised reading the [`dot2texi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dot2texi) documentation, you will find also further details on http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/documentation/.

Now, which are the pros/cons of these approaches?

In general GraphViz is used for large graphs because it's more suitable since you don't have to specify in which positions each node should be placed. With tikz-er2, instead, you should. Ultimately, this is a first parameter to decide which one use: look at the database dimensions. Notice that GraphViz place with its own algorithms the nodes, so if you really want to deploy something in a particular manner, perhaps you should come back.

With GraphViz, as it is possible to see, one should declare the styles in which all elements are drawn, even the base ones. With tikz-er2 you just have to customize a bit the aspect, but IMHO this is a minor point.

---

*Addition 17/01/2013*

Almost by chance I discovered recently that TikZ has its own `er` library: refer to section **31 Entity-Relationship Diagram Drawing Library** of the pgfmanual version October 25, 2010. The usage is almost identical to the example provided with tikz-er2.

Another approach, instead, could be *object-oriented*. Here is a possible start although a more complete and powerful version of the library is under development (repository: https://github.com/cfiandra/er-oo).

I defined a simple library `er-oo` as:

```
\usepgfmodule{oo}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes}

\definecolor{er-purple}{rgb}{.67,.51,1}
\definecolor{er-green}{rgb}{.464,.932,0}

% Entity Class
\pgfooclass{entity}{

 \attribute text;
 \attribute border color=orange;
 \attribute fill color=orange!20;
 \attribute text color=black;
 \attribute label;
 \attribute width=1.75cm;
 \attribute height=1cm;

 \method entity() {
 }

 \method text(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text}{#1}
  }

 \method set border color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{border color}{#1}
 }

 \method set fill color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{fill color}{#1}
 }

 \method set text color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text color}{#1}
 }

 \method set label(#1) {
  \pgfooset{label}{#1}
 }

 \method set width(#1) {
  \pgfooset{width}{#1}
 }

 \method set height(#1) {
  \pgfooset{height}{#1}
 }

 \method draw(#1,#2) {
  \node [rectangle,
    draw=\pgfoovalueof{border color},
    fill=\pgfoovalueof{fill color},
    text=\pgfoovalueof{text color},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) at (#1,#2) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method place(#1) {
  \node [rectangle,
    draw=\pgfoovalueof{border color},
    fill=\pgfoovalueof{fill color},
    text=\pgfoovalueof{text color},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    #1
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method connect(#1) {
  \draw[-] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(#1);
 }

 \method multi connect(#1) {
  \foreach \i in {#1}{
    \draw[-] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(\i);
  }  
 }

 \method total relation(#1) {
  \draw[-,double] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(#1);
 }

}

% Relationship Class
\pgfooclass{relationship}{

 \attribute text;
 \attribute border color=er-green;
 \attribute fill color=er-green!20;
 \attribute text color=black;
 \attribute label;
 \attribute width=1.5cm;
 \attribute height=0.75cm;

 \method relationship() {
 }

 \method text(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text}{#1}
  }

 \method set border color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{border color}{#1}
 }

 \method set fill color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{fill color}{#1}
 }

 \method set text color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text color}{#1}
 }

 \method set label(#1) {
  \pgfooset{label}{#1}
 }

 \method set width(#1) {
  \pgfooset{width}{#1}
 }

 \method set height(#1) {
  \pgfooset{height}{#1}
 }

 \method draw(#1,#2) {
  \node [diamond,
    draw=\pgfoovalueof{border color},
    fill=\pgfoovalueof{fill color},
    text=\pgfoovalueof{text color},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) at (#1,#2) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method place(#1) {
  \node [diamond,
    draw=\pgfoovalueof{border color},
    fill=\pgfoovalueof{fill color},
    text=\pgfoovalueof{text color},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    #1
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method connect(#1) {
  \draw[-] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(#1);
 }

 \method double connect(#1) {
  \draw[-,double,double distance=1.5pt] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(#1);
 }

 \method multi connect(#1) {
  \foreach \i in {#1}{
    \draw[-] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(\i);
  }  
 }

 \method total relation(#1) {
  \draw[-,double] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(#1);
 }

}

% Attribute Class
\tikzset{multi attribute/.style={double,double distance=1.5pt}}
\tikzset{derived attribute/.style={dashed}}
\tikzset{attribute type/.style={thick,#1}}

\pgfooclass{attribute}{

 \attribute text;
 \attribute border color=er-purple;
 \attribute fill color=er-purple!20;
 \attribute text color=black;
 \attribute label;
 \attribute type;
 \attribute width=1.5cm;
 \attribute height=0.35cm;

 \method attribute() {
 }

 \method text(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text}{#1}
  }

 \method set border color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{border color}{#1}
 }

 \method set fill color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{fill color}{#1}
 }

 \method set text color(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text color}{#1}
 }

 \method set label(#1) {
  \pgfooset{label}{#1}
 }

 \method set type(#1) {
  \pgfooset{type}{#1}
 }

 \method set width(#1) {
  \pgfooset{width}{#1}
 }

 \method set height(#1) {
  \pgfooset{height}{#1}
 }

 \method draw(#1,#2) {
  \node [ellipse,
    attribute type={\pgfoovalueof{type}},
    draw=\pgfoovalueof{border color},
    fill=\pgfoovalueof{fill color},
    text=\pgfoovalueof{text color},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) at (#1,#2) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method place(#1) {
  \node [ellipse,
    attribute type={\pgfoovalueof{type}},
    draw=\pgfoovalueof{border color},
    fill=\pgfoovalueof{fill color},
    text=\pgfoovalueof{text color},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    #1
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method connect(#1) {
  \draw[-] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(#1);
 }

 \method multi connect(#1) {
  \foreach \i in {#1}{
    \draw[-] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(\i);
  }  
 }

 \method total relation(#1) {
  \draw[-,double] (\pgfoovalueof{label})--(#1);
 }

}
```

thus this file should be named `tikzlibraryer-oo.code.tex` in order to be used in the document as:

```
\usetikzlibrary{er-oo}
```

Now, being sure that `tikzlibraryer-oo.code.tex` is in the same directory of the main file, in the document one could proceed as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{er-oo}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.75cm]
% new objects
\pgfoonew \myentity=new entity()
\pgfoonew \myrel=new relationship()
\pgfoonew \myattr=new attribute()

% entity tool
\myentity.set label(tool)
\myentity.text(Tool)
\myentity.draw(1,0)

\myattr.set label(tool-id)
\myattr.text(\underline{ID})
\myattr.place(left of=tool)

\myattr.set label(tool-name)
\myattr.text(Name)
\myattr.place(right of=tool)

\myentity.multi connect(tool-id,tool-name)

% relation
\myrel.set label(rel)
\myrel.text(Uses)
\myrel.place(above of=tool)
\myrel.double connect(tool)

% entity person
\myentity.set text color(blue) % just to change something with the proper method
\myentity.set label(per)
\myentity.text(Person)
\myentity.place(above of=rel)

\myattr.set label(per-id)
\myattr.text(\underline{ID})
\myattr.place(left of=per)

\myattr.set type(derived attribute)
\myattr.set label(per-age)
\myattr.text(Age)
\myattr.place(right of=per)

\myattr.set type() % to reset the derived attribute style
\myattr.set label(per-name)
\myattr.text(Name)
\myattr.place(above left of=per)

\myattr.set type(multi attribute)
\myattr.set label(per-phone)
\myattr.text(Phone)
\myattr.place(above of=per)

\myattr.set type() % to reset the multi attribute style
\myattr.set label(per-addr)
\myattr.text(Address)
\myattr.place(above right of=per)

\myattr.set label(street)
\myattr.text(Street)
\myattr.place(above right of=per-addr)
\myattr.connect(per-addr)

\myattr.set label(city)
\myattr.text(City)
\myattr.place(right of=per-addr)
\myattr.connect(per-addr)

\myentity.multi connect(per-id,per-age,per-name,per-phone,per-addr,rel)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: "it's not available on CTAN" ... and why not??

Comment: When I discovered it during a database course I search it on http://ctan.org/search/ without success: if I'm wrong please let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I wanted to say that I do not like it that a lot of people _take_ a lot from CTAN but often don't give something back.

Comment: Oh, sorry: now I see your point `:)`. I agree with you: the community benefit a lot when a package is on CTAN.

Comment: @Clément: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Just edited :)

Comment: You should include a reference to your excellent paper, https://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT015/drawing-ER-diagrams-with-TikZ.pdf !