# Which database documentation software do you use for LaTeX (in Linux)?

Tags: database

I am looking for a database documentation software where I want to incorporate the output in LaTeX. I want to show the table structures, primary keys and other related information.

I found pst-dbicons (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-dbicons) at CTAN. I will forced to use this if I don't find an alternative. But I am not exactly looking for an ER diagram software.

Comment: Looks like graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/ER.html) could be an option.

Comment: You could perhaps be interested in seeing [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78357/drawing-relationships-between-elements-of-a-database).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the comments and web search, eventually I came up with a working framework for my purpose which might be useful for others.

- Open your database schema using  phpMyAdmin (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). Select `Export` tab, quick export method, format SQL. Click `Go`. Your schema will be save as a SQL file.`sqlt-graph <sql file name>`

[image]

- Process the SQL file from previous step using `sqlt-graph` (http://search.cpan.org/dist/SQL-Translator/script/sqlt-graph). One specific example command could be,

> *sqlt-graph  --show-datatypes -l dot -n record -f MySQL -t png     --graphattr center,margin="0.0,0.0",overlap=false,sep=10,size="20.0,14,0",orientation=landscape --nodeattr fontsize=24,fontname=Helvetica  --edgeattr weight=0.05,len=2.0   -o output.png input.sql*

- This produces a `.png` file which can be used in LaTeX or anywhere else.
- When included in LaTeX, the output looks something like this
  *(partially smudged out to preserve confidentiality)*.

[image: Sample output from real life]

Comment: For better results, I suggest to use PS or SVG(Z) format.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks. Yes, in that case we will have to use `-t ps` or `-t svg` instead of `-t png`.