# Use Case diagrams , UML diagrams and E-R diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-uml, pgf-umlcd

Does LaTeX allow to draw **Use Case Diagrams**, **UML Diagrams** and **E-R Diagrams**. How to implement these? What packages to use?

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83200/14103) help?

Comment: For ER diagrams, you may want to have a look to [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78357/13304): some methods are shown.