# Document Database Scheme

Tags: database, mysql

I wonder if there is any good method to document the relations between tables from a MySQL (or any other database) in LaTeX?

I found this thread [Which database documentation software do you use for LaTeX (in Linux)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83200/which-database-documentation-software-do-you-use-for-latex-in-linux) which is close to what I have in mind, but given that posting is more than a few years old, I assume there is something else that does the job.

I would like to use my database (about 20 tables, some with lots of columns) as a starting point and add some annotations (arrows that connect two columns from different tables for example.

Comment: The basic idea is still the same: Do the processing outside of LaTeX. I don't know if there's something generating a tikzpicture, but the linked post contains the option to generate a SVG which you could edit with Inkscape to be "TeX compatible" (export).