# Package for drawing RDF graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Is there some package to draw nice RDF
graphs, such as the one below (taken from [there](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hahf9lwgol6lz3k/RDFgraph.png))?

Can such a graph (with the same style) be produced in TikZ?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: The graph, per se, is not a problem: you can find several Q/A on how to do graphs (just use an `ellipse` shape), for example [How to draw graphs in Latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57152/13304). For the "liquid" background, instead, you might follow as approach [Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71064/13304).

Comment: Start from these examples http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/ and http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/

Comment: Do you really insist on RDF?

Comment: If my answer satisfies your needs could you consider to accept it? As a new user, I would courteously suggest you for the future to upvote all answers you find useful, including those to others' questions and to check/accept the best answers to your own questions by clicking the green tick on the left-hand side of the answer. This will help the community.

Answer (score 35):

As first think I would start to define the style able to represent the vertices; we basically need:

1. an ellipse;
2. some size definitions;
3. drawing the border thicker and setting the fill color brighter with respect to the border;
4. making the text in white color;
5. perhaps reduce a bit the size of the text font.

The style definition in TikZ can be done via `\tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{vertex style/.style={
    draw=#1,
    thick,
    fill=#1!70,
    text=white,
    ellipse,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    font=\small,
    outer sep=3pt, % the usage of this option will be clear later on
  },
}
```

Notice two things: this style receives an argument, the color and sets the fill color brighter by mixing the color with white. Secondly, the `ellipse` shape requires the library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
```

Let's now create the first vertex. I would start with the "Righteous Kill" which has most connections departing from.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,png,border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % required for the ellipse shape
\tikzset{vertex style/.style={
    draw=#1,
    thick,
    fill=#1!70,
    text=white,
    ellipse,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    font=\small,
    outer sep=3pt,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[vertex style=Turquoise] (Rk) {Righteous Kill};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Beware of the option `dvipsnames`: it has been necessary to set this within the class options to prevent a possible `option clash` error since TikZ loads itself `xcolor`.

The node uses the style defined above setting its color (definition in the `xcolor` manual), its name `(Rk)` and its text `{Righteous Kill}`.

The result:

[image]

From now on, I won't display any time the preamble, but rather just the picture code.

Second step is to locate the other nodes. One might exploit lots of possibilities (using GraphViz, using the object-oriented module of PGF and build some custom class - see: [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78357/drawing-relationships-between-elements-of-a-database#82600)): here I use the `positioning` library of TikZ. Each vertex, therefore, will be located starting from the position of other vertices by referring to their names.

Notice: since each vertex needs to be connected to another one, the syntax

```
\node[options] (a) {text a} ... edge[options] node[options]{text conn} (b);
```

will connect the vertices `a` and `b` setting a label to the connection `text conn`. Extremely useful in this case. Indeed, let's start to add another node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.75cm,>=stealth']
\node[vertex style=Turquoise] (Rk) {Righteous Kill};

\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, above of=Rk,xshift=2em] (BD) {Bryan Dennehy}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style,above]{starring} (Rk);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The options `node distance=2.75cm,>=stealth'` concern the basic vertex distance and the type of the arrow tip used for the connection. Due to the arrow tip selected, the library `arrows` should be loaded.

Notice that the connection text requires a style: `text style`. Its definition is:

```
\tikzset{
  text style/.style={
    sloped, % the text will be parallel to the connection 
    text=black,
    font=\footnotesize,
    above
  }
}
```

The location of the new node is done via the options `above of=Rk,xshift=2em`: the first one sets the position in relation to the name of the previous node we created before, the second one shifts a bit on the right this position.

Result:

[image]

Once understood this mechanism, it is possible to locate all the other nodes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.75cm,>=stealth']
\node[vertex style=Turquoise] (Rk) {Righteous Kill};

\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, above of=Rk,xshift=2em] (BD) {Bryan Dennehy}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{starring} (Rk);

\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, right=1.5cm of Rk,yshift=4ex] (AP) {Al Pacino}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{starring} (Rk); 

\node[vertex style=red, below right of=Rk,xshift=2em] (JA) {John Avnet}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{director} (Rk); 

 \node[vertex style=BurntOrange, right=1.5cm of Rk,yshift=-4ex] (RN) {Robert De Niro}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{starring} (Rk); 

\node[vertex style=MidnightBlue, above right of=Rk,xshift=2em] (Dr) {Drama}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{genre} (Rk); 

\node[vertex style=Maroon, below of=Rk,xshift=-2em] (Skf) {Serial Killer Films}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{subject} (Rk);

\node[vertex style=Maroon, below right of=Skf] (Cf) {Crime Films}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{broader} (Skf);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Once this task is done, it is possible to start adding the "liquid" background around some vertices.

To place something in background the library `backgrounds` is of help, as well as the `hobby` library by Andrew Stacey to draw the smooth curve. Moreover, often some computation are needed, therefore also the library `calc` should be loaded.

The path definition should be done as follows: starting from the north of the node `(Rk)`, one circumnavigates all possible anchors of the interested nodes to be highlighted. There are some automatic tools, see [Hobby path realization in convex hull approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/hobby-path-realization-in-convex-hull-approach), but they can not be precise and fine tune things as some manual work can do. And, in this case this allows, to achieve a best result.

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[Maroon,fill=Maroon,dashed,fill opacity=0.1](Rk.north) 
to[closed,curve through={(Rk.north west).. (Rk.west) .. (Rk.south west) 
..($(Rk.south west)!0.5!(Skf.north)$) .. (Skf.north     west).. (Skf.west) 
.. (Skf.south west) .. ($(Skf.south)!0.75!(Cf.west)$) .. (Cf.west) 
.. (Cf.south west) .. (Cf.south) .. (Cf.south east) .. (Cf.east) 
.. ($(Cf.north east)!0.65!(Skf.south east)$) .. (Skf.east) 
.. (Skf.north east).. ($(Skf.north)!0.35!(Rk.south east)$) 
.. (Rk.south east) .. (Rk.east)..(Rk.north east)}](Rk.north);
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

More or less that's the code... but that's the result:

[image]

The mysterious option `outer sep=3pt` allows to not have the "liquid background" too much close to the border shape. And now it's all!

The complete code for reference:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,png,border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % required for the ellipse shape
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, backgrounds, calc, hobby, positioning}

% this avoides some problem with the hobby implementation
% egreg's code from:
% http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/83195-la-libreria-hobby-tikz-non-funziona-piu#83203
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_if_exist:NF \prg_stepwise_function:nnnN { \cs_gset_eq:NN \prg_stepwise_function:nnnN \int_step_function:nnnN }
\cs_if_exist:NF \prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn { \cs_gset_eq:NN \prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn \int_step_inline:nnnn }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{vertex style/.style={
    draw=#1,
    thick,
    fill=#1!70,
    text=white,
    ellipse,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    font=\small,
    outer sep=3pt,
  },
  text style/.style={
    sloped,
    text=black,
    font=\footnotesize,
    above
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.75cm,>=stealth']
\node[vertex style=Turquoise] (Rk) {Righteous Kill};

\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, above of=Rk,xshift=2em] (BD) {Bryan Dennehy}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{starring} (Rk);

\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, right=1.5cm of Rk,yshift=4ex] (AP) {Al Pacino}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{starring} (Rk); 

\node[vertex style=red, below right of=Rk,xshift=2em] (JA) {John Avnet}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{director} (Rk); 

 \node[vertex style=BurntOrange, right=1.5cm of Rk,yshift=-4ex] (RN) {Robert De Niro}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{starring} (Rk); 

\node[vertex style=MidnightBlue, above right of=Rk,xshift=2em] (Dr) {Drama}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{genre} (Rk); 

\node[vertex style=Maroon, below of=Rk,xshift=-2em] (Skf) {Serial Killer Films}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{subject} (Rk);

\node[vertex style=Maroon, below right of=Skf] (Cf) {Crime Films}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style]{broader} (Skf);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[Maroon,fill=Maroon,dashed,fill opacity=0.1](Rk.north) 
to[closed,curve through={(Rk.north west).. (Rk.west) .. (Rk.south west) 
..($(Rk.south west)!0.5!(Skf.north)$) .. (Skf.north     west).. (Skf.west) 
.. (Skf.south west) .. ($(Skf.south)!0.75!(Cf.west)$) .. (Cf.west) 
.. (Cf.south west) .. (Cf.south) .. (Cf.south east) .. (Cf.east) 
.. ($(Cf.north east)!0.65!(Skf.south east)$) .. (Skf.east) 
.. (Skf.north east).. ($(Skf.north)!0.35!(Rk.south east)$) 
.. (Rk.south east) .. (Rk.east)..(Rk.north east)}](Rk.north);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I needed to install packages 1) [hobby](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/hobby), 2) [l3kernel](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel), 3) [xparse](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

Comment: @CoderaPurpa: if you have a non complete distribution, yes. :) Personally, I always recommend to have it, because one does not have to think about requirements to make working any piece of code.

Comment: Where do I find more information about the `($(Skf.south)!0.75!(Cf.west)$)` notation and what it does?

Comment: @white_gecko: look for `calc` library in the pgfmanual