# RDF graph draw using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

When I use the following code to draw an RDF graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.75cm,>=stealth']
\node[vertex style=Turquoise] (Rk) {Righteous Kill};

\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, above of=Rk,xshift=2em] (BD) {Bryan Dennehy}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style,above]{starring} (Rk);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the following error:

```
Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'stealth''.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.150 ...picture}[node distance=2.75cm,>=stealth']
```

How can I solve it please

Comment: please, provide complete small document. it seems that you have missed libraries in your document preamble.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` or, preferably, update the deprecated syntax and use `arrows.meta`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to have googled the [relevant styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107028/121799). As Torbjørn T. suggests, you should either load the `arrows` library or better the `arrows.meta` library, in which case you also need to update the arrow head.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,png,border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta} %<added arrows.meta
% for the original stealth' you'd have to load arrows instead
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107028/121799
\tikzset{vertex style/.style={
    draw=#1,
    thick,
    fill=#1!70,
    text=white,
    ellipse,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    font=\small,
    outer sep=3pt,
  },
  text style/.style={
    sloped,
    text=black,
    font=\footnotesize,
    above
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.75cm,>={Stealth[]}]
\node[vertex style=Turquoise] (Rk) {Righteous Kill};
\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, above of=Rk,xshift=2em] (BD) {Bryan Dennehy}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style,above]{starring} (Rk);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I will be happy to remove this answer, I just posted it as an alternative to [sab hoque's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442131/121799), which, at time of writing this, does not provide a compilable code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a upper case S so like this (not fully sure if that will solve the problem):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.75cm,>=Stealth]
\node[vertex style=Turquoise] (Rk) {Righteous Kill};

\node[vertex style=BurntOrange, above of=Rk,xshift=2em] (BD) {Bryan Dennehy}
 edge [<-,cyan!60!blue] node[text style,above]{starring} (Rk);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: without knowing, what op have in document preamble, this is only guessing/speculations. we need to wait on her/his response.

Comment: @sab hoque, you should delete even the '

Comment: The `stealth'` arrow tip (note `'` at the end) is from the old `arrows` library. This is what bib used. The `Stealth` arrow tip is from the newer `arrows.meta` library. To use the first you need `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` in the preamble, as cfr mentioned above. To use the second you need `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`, you should probably update your answer to include that, your code will not work without it.