# How to draw RDF graphs in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Is there any solution for drawing simple graphs in LaTeX like the following?
I came across tikz but couldn't figure out how to do it. Are there also possibilities to extend such graphs without caring too much about node distances etc?

[image]

Comment: One option: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\tikzset{
myell/.style={
  draw,
  ellipse
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2cm]
\node[myell] 
  (sub) {Subject};
\node[myell,right=of sub] 
  (obj) {Object};
\draw[->]
  (sub) -- node[above]{Predicate} (obj);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You might even be interested in [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78357/13304).