# How (if it possible) to do a certain type of scheme in latex

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I am in the middle of writing something exposing various interactions between various properties that have certains objects in some theory in mathematics. I would like to summerize this in a graphe, and I would like it to look like this :

[image]

I started to try to do this (without the ellipses...) with the package xypic (that I already use for my diagrams) thanks to the following example stated in the documentation of the package :

```
\entrymodifiers={++[o][F-]}
\SelectTips{cm}{}
\xymatrix @-1pc
{
    *\txt{start} \ar[r]
    & 0 \ar@(r,u)[]^b \ar[r]_a
    & 1 \ar[r]^b \ar@(r,d)[]_a
    & 2 \ar[r]^b
    \ar ‘dr_l[l] ‘_ur[l] _(.2)a [l]
    &*++[o][F=]{3}
    \ar ‘ur^l[lll]‘^dr[lll]^b [lll]
    \ar ‘dr_l[ll] ‘_ur[ll] [ll]
}
```

but I am really not happy with it.

So I wonder if a package devoted to the design of intricate graphs as the one in the graphical example does exist, or at least something apporaching. If not, what would tex-gurus advise in my case ?

I must precise that I would like to avoid using tikz (except if there a dedicated "module" of it answering to my question, but I don't think so) nor any kind of really graphism-oriented latex package if possible, and if the eventual other solution produces diagrams of quality compared to those that tikz would produce.

Comment: Best strategy for such a diagram? Graphviz, definitely. In addition, its output can be integrated in LaTeX documents. Have a look to [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78357/13304).

Comment: Ok, I have tried the example "Here is the GraphViz method" in the accepted answer from the link you are pointing to, and it produces a white page with page number 1. No trace of the diagram...

Comment: Not that I'd especially recommend it for this but what is supposed to be poor about the *quality* of TiKZ diagrams? [I think it would be very annoying to use it for this but, if you did, I can't see why you should get a high quality result. It just wouldn't be a very efficient way to produce it unless you were just very familiar with TiKZ and so used it rather than learn something new.]

Comment: Did you compile with shell escape enabled? Do you have the software installed?

Comment: @cfr Yes. No. But I don't like the idea of installing software to do this. I will therefore rather try the example given in the edit of the accepted answer, using tikz.

Comment: Why not just say that rather than saying it doesn't work as though there is some mystery about why?

Comment: @RobertGreen: Of course if you don't have graphviz installed you can't compile the example. And, of course, if you don't want to use TikZ, you don't like the idea to install software, you can certainly find other more laboriuos methods. It will just take you more time.

Comment: @cfr I thought there was something more to install than graphviz-2.38, but was wrong. So I confirm, as I said, it produces a white page with page number 1. No trace of the diagram.

Comment: @cfr And hedging myself from another remark of yours, let me precise that I put graphviz in my PATH.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Do you have graphviz installed to test the example?

Comment: Finally, after investigating the "market" a bit more, I opted for pstricks. It could appear complicated, but it's not that much complicated, and I will be able to work in greater generality with it, so that it is perfect.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, I have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments by the OP using a different graphics package.

Comment: @PaulGessler Did not know that this was a valid reason to vote for closing. ;-)

Comment: Well, one can enter whatever he/she wants as a close reason. The alternative is for you to self-answer your question, because without that it won't be useful to future visitors, hence why I voted to close.